# Creating a list of ordered pairs in lambda calculus using recursion

Tags: recursion, lambda, lambda-calculus, calculus

My input is two lists being l = [x1, x2, x3,...,xn] and k = [y1, y2, y3,...,yn]

I want a y = [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)...(xn,yn)] output.

How can I apply recursion to my code? I could do it for the first item with
         `f = \l k. (cons (pair (head l) (head k)) empty)` but I don't understand exactly how do I use recursion to create the other items.

The function "head" returns the first item of a list and the function "tail" returns a list without the first item.

Comment: In lambda calculus? Which representation of lists are you using? How do you represent pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Naturally it depends precisely on how you've implemented tuples, lists, etc. in Lambda Calculus. But assuming standard functional `cons` lists, and that both lists are the same length, and that you already have defined the following helpers, some of which you have already cited:

```
cons    -- construct a list from a node and another list
empty   -- the empty list
head    -- retrieve the first node value of a list
tail    -- retrieve all but the first node of a list
pair    -- pair values into a tuple
isEmpty -- return `true` if a list is `empty`, `false` otherwise
true    -- return the first argument
false   -- return the second argument
```

Then we can recursively zip the lists as follows:

```
ZIP = λlk. isEmpty l -- "if the list is empty…"
           empty     -- "return an empty result. Else…"
           (cons     -- "return a new list, containing…"
               (pair (head l) (head k))  -- "the zipped heads, and…"
               (ZIP  (tail l) (tail k))) -- "everything else zipped."
```

The problem of course is that the raw lambda calculus doesn't *have* recursion. You cannot refer to a function name within its own definition. The answer is to use a [fixed-point combinator, e.g. the famous `Y` combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator).

```
ZIP = Y (λzlk. isEmpty l empty (cons (pair (head l) (head k)) (z (tail l) (tail k)))
```

The definition of `Y` is:

```
Y = λf.(λx.f(x x))(λx.f(x x))
```

Untangling how precisely this *works* is an impressive bit of mental gymnastics that is not quite in scope for this question, but *using* it is pretty simple. In general, if you have a desired (but illegal, in raw LC) recursive definition like this:

```
R = λ ??? . ??? R ???
```

You can instead write it as the totally legal, non-recursive definition:

```
R = Y (λr ??? . ??? r ???)
```

In other words, add a new parameter to your function which *stands in* for your recursive function, and use `Y` to wire up everything for you. That `Y` can invent recursion from scratch is extraordinary and the reason it is so famous.